# Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно выполнить задание

Tags: swift, optional

Создать две опциональные переменные типа `Float`. Одной из них задать первоначальное значение. Написать функцию, которая принимает на вход опциональную переменную типа `Float`. Функция должна безопасно извлечь значение из входящей переменной. Если значение удалось получить - необходимо вывести его в консоль, если значение у переменной отсутствует вывести в консоль фразу "Variable can't be unwrapped". Вызвать функцию дважды с двумя ранее созданными переменными.

```
 var firstnum : Float? = 1.6
 var secondnum : Float?

 func result(num : Float?) {
  if firstnum != nil && secondnum != nil {
   print(firstnum!)
   print(secondnum!)
  }
  else {
   print("Variable can't be unwrapped")
 }
}
result(num: firstnum)
result(num: secondnum)
```

Comment: "Одной из них задать первоначальное значение." - где? "Написать функцию, которая принимает на вход опциональную переменную" - где? "Вызвать функцию дважды" - где?

Comment: я бы как рах хотел узнать как мне все это правильно расписать в коде. Простите я еще совсем новичок в этом)

Comment: Нет, Вы спросили - правильно ли Вы *выполнили* задание.

Comment: Да, но не могли бы вы подсказать как правильно его выполнить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно проверить, что параметр, который передается в функцию, не является nil. Для этого используйте unwrapping через if let:

```
var firstnum: Float? = 1.6
var secondnum: Float?

 func result(num: Float?) {
  if let num = num {
   print(num)
  }
  else {
   print("Variable can't be unwrapped")
 }
}
result(num: firstnum)
result(num: secondnum)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь)